# ASP.NET web forms button doesn't fire when cbpScroller.js is included

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms page which works fine, all buttons fire, and all events are handled properly, until I include cbpScroller.js into the page.

The form is made of 3 sections each one has an anchor that scrolls to the next one on postback as seen below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext ctx = this.Context;
    clientIP = ctx.Request.UserHostAddress;

    if (IsPostBack)
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Hash", "location.hash = '#aLoc';", true);
}
```

I included all other .js scripts in the aspx page at the the bottom of the page, but when I include this one, the first button fires, and the second one does nothing. There isn't even any debugging output.

I tried to register the script on startup via:

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("cbScroller", ResolveUrl("js/cbpScroller.js")`

in Page_Load, but still no results. Has anyone experienced this before. Thanks advance!

Comment: What is cbpScroller.js? Where is it from? Did you write it?

Comment: this is where the web dev got it from:   http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/18/on-scroll-effect-layout/